# React - Focus on a child element

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to add focus on the i'th child element using the following procedure:

```
handleFocusing: function() {
  var children = React.Children.toArray(this.props.children);
  var index = calculateFocusIndex(children);

  if (index !== -1) {
    ReactDOM.findDOMNode(children[index]).focus();
  }
}
```

However, the `ReactDOM.findDOMNode()` function is throwing the following error:

`Uncaught Error: Invariant Violation: Element appears to be neither ReactComponent nor DOMNode (keys: $$typeof,type,key,ref,props,_owner,_store)`

Comment: what does calculateFocusIndex calculate exactly ?

Comment: Are you trying to focus to the first focusable element, or trying to focus to a specific element?

Comment: A specific child indicated by `index`. `calculateFocusIndex` just gives a number of the index to focus.